# JWT and large Roles data best Practice?

Tags: http, security, jwt

We are trying to build the authentication with JSON WEB TOKEN (JWT). The problem is  that we can have many roles data that will include module id and operations id for specific operation. So roles data can be quite large( more than allowed 8kb data).
The solution might be that jwt token and roles list can be sent separately to user.
 Question: what is best practice to handle this situation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this data, and also what you think JWT is intended to be used for?  8kb sounds pretty massive in terms of claims in a JWT.

Comment: Yes. That's why are going to use separate request for roles. The main drawback of this approach is maintaining two states instead one(token and roles).thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [role based access with jwt and a lot of roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56847638/role-based-access-with-jwt-and-a-lot-of-roles)

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari I think both answers have valid points. Thanks for pointing that post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the token will be sent in each request, you should avoid *"excessively long tokens"* otherwise you'll have a big overhead in your requests.

You could create another endpoint to provide extra details about the user roles. Something like `GET /users/me` or `GET /users/me/roles`.

Comment: Yes so seems it is the only recommended solution. We are going to use separate request for roles. The main drawback of this approach is maintaining two auth states instead one(token and roles) which can be error prone and not secure.